# How can I filter a query by post id?

Tags: wp-query

In my wp_postmeta table, I have the following values:

[image]

I'm trying query the posts whose ID lie in the `meta_value` column associated to a given post (the current post being viewed).

For example, lets suppose I'm viewing post `94`. As illustrated above I would like to retrieve the posts `108,78,90` associated with `94` and display their titles.

In this way the an area (post type) is associated with a post by its ID being one of the meta values for the post's 'area' meta key.

I start with this:

```
$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'area',
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
      );

      $areas = new WP_Query($args);
```

But how I can specify I want the posts associated with the post `94`?

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to you question? If possible add examples for better explanation here

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is really unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: the screenshot is saying **areas**, but the query is written with **area** - is that correct?

Comment: Might be overcomplicating things, but connecting post types to post types might be a good job for [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/)

Comment: Hi @marcelo2605 if you have follow up questions, please create a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the values `108,78,90` corresponding to the meta key 'areas' for the post with ID 94?

First retrieve those IDs:

```
$the_post_id = 94;
$area_ids = get_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'areas', false );

//Make sure they're all positive integers
$area_ids = array_map( 'absint', $area_ids );

if( $area_ids ){
   //We have IDs, retrieve posts
   $areas = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'area',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post__in' => $area_ids;
   ));

   if( $areas ){
       //We have areas
       foreach( $areas as $area ){
          echo get_the_title( $area ). '<br/>';
       }
   }

}
```

The above has not been tested, but should work in theory. If you want `$the_post_id` to the be ID of the post currently being viewed then you can use `get_the_ID()`.